# jQuery daterangepicker: executes alert twice?

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I want it to alert "ok" when you change/make a date. But i get two alerts instead of one?

How can i fix this?

here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
   $('#datePicking')
       .daterangepicker({
       arrows:true,
       onChange: function(){
           $('#Viewer')
           alert('ok');
       }
       }); 
});
```

here's a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/BU5PJ/2/

jquery 1.4.4, UI 1.8.5,  + [daterangepicker from filamentgroup.com](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/)

Comment: The code is on the link provided.

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of the documentation found here http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

> onChange: function, callback that
>   executes whenever the date input
>   changes (can happen twice on range
>   selections).

When I picked a specific date I only got one alert box.

Comment: try picking "today" or "last 7 days"

Comment: Maybe the two alerts specify the before and after dates.

Comment: "last 7 day" is date range (so in terms of those docs, you'd expect two alert), it also treats "today" as a date range also. The site does say it's a work in progress, maybe you could suggest an improvement to the site, because it looks like a limitation of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(
 function(){
 $('#datePicking')
   .daterangepicker({
   arrows:true,
   onClose : function(){
       $('#Viewer')
       alert('ok');
    }
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using daterangepicker with angular. My purpose is to watch any change in the model that stores the date range value and save it for an AJAX call later. I face the same issue as it hits the event twice whenever the date is changed even if I select 'Today': **Once it is object with startDate and endDate properties, and the other time it is a string**.

It **can be made use of as an advantage.**

```
    $scope.$watch(
    'rangeOfDate',
    function (newValue) {
        // Due to a known bug of open source library daterangepicker, the event is hit twice 
        //upon change. Once it is an object, and once it is a string. So, use appropriately.
        var selectedDateRange = new Object();
        if (typeof (newValue) == 'object') {
            selectedDateRange.startDate = new Date(newValue.startDate).toLocaleDateString();
            selectedDateRange.endDate = new Date(newValue.endDate).toLocaleDateString();
            //Do as you wish with this custom object
        }
        else if (typeof (newValue) == 'string') {
            alert("string");
        }               
    },
    false);
```